# Why I am getting status of 404 (Not Found) when I am trying to use the avatar which I have uploaded using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

I have created a todo-app with a login feature. Here a User can register themself and add their todos. User can update their information in the account section. User can also upload their avatar. And if any user ever forgot their password then they can reset their password by going to the reset password page, and then a reset password link will be sent to their registered email Id.

You can see the live app here [ToDo](https://app---todo.herokuapp.com/)

Everything works fine the only problem is that when user upload their avatar and login into the website after a day then the avatar is broken and in console it shows `Failed to load resource: {filename} the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I don't know why I am getting this error. It is working fine when user is uploading there avatar but it stop working after a day or so.

Here is my code

***Routes***

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const { catchErrors } = require('../handlers/errorHandlers');

router.get('/account', authController.checkLogIn, userController.account);
router.post(
    '/account',
    userController.upload,
    catchErrors(userController.resize),
    catchErrors(userController.updateAccount)
);

module.exports = router;
```

***Controller***

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const multer = require('multer');
const jimp = require('jimp');
const uuid = require('uuid');

// setting the options for multer
const multerOption = {
    // we are storing the file in memory
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
    // checking the fileType
    fileFilter(req, file, next) {
        const isAvatar = file.mimetype.startsWith('image/');
        if (isAvatar) next(null, true);
        else next({ message: "That filetype isn't allowed!" }, false);
    },
};

// rendering the user account 
exports.account = (req, res) => {
    res.render('account', { title: 'Your Account' });
};

// reading the file
exports.upload = multer(multerOption).single('avatar');

// after reading the file we are resizing the file
exports.resize = async (req, res, next) => {
    // checking if there is no new file to resize
    if (!req.file) return next();
    const extension = req.file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    req.body.avatar = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`;

    // resizing the photo
    const avatar = await jimp.read(req.file.buffer);
    await avatar.resize(800, 800);

    // writing the photo in our filesystem
    await avatar.write(`./public/uploads/${req.body.avatar}`);
    next();
};

// updating the user account 
exports.updateAccount = async (req, res) => {
    let updates = {
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        email: req.body.email,
    };

    // if user has requested to update the avatart then only change the avatar if we dont't do that then it will set the default avatar
    if (req.file) updates.avatar = req.body.avatar;

    // finally find the user and update the information
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        { $set: updates },
        { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
    );

    req.flash('success', 'Updated');
    res.redirect('/account');
};
```

***account.pug***

```
extends layout 

block left-content 

    .manage--account

        h4 Manage Your Account 

        .account--name 
            .user--avatar
                if user.avatar
                    img.circle.responsive-img(src= `/uploads/${user.avatar}` alt=user.name )
                else
                    img.circle.responsive-img(src=user.gravatar + '&d=retro' alt=user.name )

            .user--name 
                p.name #{user.name}
                p.username= `@${user.username}`

block right-content 
    .user--form
        .container
            .container
                .card.blue-grey.lighten-5
                    .card-content
                        form.col.s12(action="/account" method="POST" enctype ="multipart/form-data") 
                            .row
                                .input-field.col.s12
                                    input#name(type="text" name="name" value=user.name required) 
                                    label(for="name") Update Name

                                .input-field.col.s12
                                    input#username(type="text" name="username" value=user.username required) 
                                    label(for="username") Update Username

                                .input-field.col.s12
                                    input#bio(type="text" name="bio" value=`${ user.bio || 'While there is life there is a hope!'}`) 
                                    label(for="bio") Update Bio

                                .input-field.col.s12
                                    input#email.validate(type="email" name="email" value=user.email required) 
                                    label(for="email") Update Email-Id
                                    span.helper-text(data-error="We can’t quite understand that email address. Can you try again?" data-success="")

                                label(for="avatar").col.s12 Change Avatar
                                    br
                                    br
                                    input(type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg")

                            br
                            .row.action--btn
                                br
                                button.btn(type="submit" name="action") Update
```

I have also joined the path in the `app.js`

```
// folder were all pug files are stored
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// serves up static files from the public folder. Anything in public/ will just be served up as the file it is
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Can any one please help me I am not able to understand that where I am making the mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your exact issue (https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), but Heroku describe their file system as ephemeral. Maybe it would be more reliable if you store the avatar in something like AWS S3 (instead of writing to file system). That way it's persistent until you delete it from S3.

Comment: can you share the code for this method userController.account

Comment: @MohamedMirghani i have added it in the code. there was nothing much in the ```userController.account``` you can also see the complete code here https://github.com/amankumar6/ToDo

Comment: thats wierd, does the same error happens localy ?! if not I think it is related to Heroku as @chillin suggested

Comment: no it doesn't happen locally. I guess its Heroku related problem